# fail2ban permission denied on script

Tags: permissions, python, daemon, selinux, fail2ban

I've just upgraded from RHEL 5 to 6.5 and setup `fail2ban` anew. I can't seem to get my custom action to work now, supposedly because of a permission issue. I wan't to know what am I doing wrong, and how can I make `fail2ban` run the script successfully.

I have a `fail2ban` action set up to run a generic shell script. I prefer things this way.

```
actionstart = <script> <jail> start
```

Where `<script>` is specified in the `jail.local` file:

```
action   = run-script[jail=drupal-reg-lim,script=/path/to/script.sh]
```

But I get a 126 exit code when I try to run the script, which, according to [tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html), means that there is a "Permission problem or command is not an executable".

This happens regardless of the contents of `script.sh` - whether it is completely empty, or only has a shebang (`#!/bin/sh`). Trying to run `sudo /path/to/script.sh` works.

I tried changing the `actionstart` so that it would log, and placed the script as `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/script.sh`:

```
actionstart = <script> <jail> start || logger -dit fail2ban-run-script <script> <jail> start failed: exitcode = $?
```

Actually outputs the following into `/var/log/messages`:

```
Apr 23 05:49:25 xx1 fail2ban-run-script[8236]: /etc/fail2ban/action.d/script.sh drupal-reg-lim start failed: exitcode = 126
```

Also trying to run `sh` works. Only running a script fails. I also tried `chmod 777 script.sh`:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      10 Apr 23 05:12 script.sh
```

Another thought was that this might have to do with the SELinux security context (logging `id` output gave me `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:system_r:fail2ban_t:s0`), but I haven't been successful at testing this (`sudo -t fail2ban_t -r system_r /bin/sh` fails with `Permission denied` even though `fail2ban` can run `sh`; I might be doing something wrong in my `sudo`).

Something that might be useful to know is that `fail2ban` uses Python's `os.system()` to execute the command. But my attempt at recreating it this way has failed too:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.system('/etc/fail2ban/action.d/script.sh || echo "No"')
0
```

All of this leaves me with nothing. I'd be glad to get any kind of help.

(Side note: actually, `fail2ban` didn't get the 126 exit code for some reason, and simply spit out an error with a code of 0x7e00, which means the process has stopped but the exit code is zero. Took me some time to figure out, so thought I'd share.)

Comment: At least the github version of [fail2ban uses `subprocess.Popen` to run shell commands](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/fail2ban/server/action.py#L502). `shell=True` implies that it tries to run it as `/bin/sh -c ...`. Enable debugging log level to see the actual command

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found the solution, which had nothing to do with Python. Mind you, that I have the RHEL version of fail2ban, which uses `os.system()`. Adding a log message to print out the exact command used made me eventually get to the answer (see below). I would like to understand, though, how would you suggest that I enable debugging log level without changing code? I guess that's another question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it had nothing to do with anything except for an error in the script I was trying to run!

Specifically, the script I was calling, was trying to run another script which is located in the same directory. To get the name of the common directory, rather than using `BASE_DIR=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))` I accidently wrote `BASE_DIR=$(readlink -f "$0")`, and needless to say, `"${BASE_DIR}/another_script.sh arg1 arg2..."` failed (it was trying to run the non-existing non-sense path `/path/to/script.sh/another_script.sh`) with status code 126.